# Stopping Cassandra in Shell script

Tags: bash, cassandra

What shell command would you use to stop Cassandra started locally? Is there one that stops it without the PID? If no, what command can you use to get the PID in shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Please tailor to your individual situation, since you mentioned that C* is started locally.

However you can use something like this in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$(cat /var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid)
sudo kill -9 $PID
```

Comment: This makes sense but do you know can you help me understand why I get this error?

cat: /var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid: No such file or directory
usage: kill [-s signal_name] pid ...
       kill -l [exit_status]
       kill -signal_name pid ...
       kill -signal_number pid ...

Comment: `cat` is reporting that the file doesn't exist, at least in that location. My question then becomes: "is cassandra running?" If cassandra isn't running, then have your script create an error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you started Cassandra *without* designating a file for the PID, then you'll have to do something tricky, like this:

```
ps -ef | grep cassandra | grep "jmx\.local\.port=7199" | awk '{print $2}'

96165
```

Basically you're using `ps` to get the status of all processes, `grep`ping for "cassandra", and then `grep`ping for something very specific to the Cassandra process (like local JMX on port 7199).  Then, if you pipe that all through `awk`, you can pretty easily just pull the second space-delimited "column."

There's probably a more graceful way to do this, but it'll work.

Then, as a user with privileges to the cassandra process, you can just run a `kill` on that PID.  Or, you could encapsulate that all into one, single command:

```
kill $(ps -ef | grep cassandra | grep "jmx\.local\.port=7199" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Stopping a local Cassandra instance depends on the installation type.

If you've installed Cassandra as a YUM (RHEL/CentOS) or APT (Debian) package, stop the service with:

```
$ sudo service cassandra stop
```

If you've installed Cassandra using the binary tarball, you can simply kill it with:

```
$ pkill cassandra
```

Note that if you're running Cassandra as another user such as `root`, you'll need to use `sudo` to get elevated permissions. Cheers!